# Making dependant objects in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I apologize for the way of formulating my question and problem. I am a newbie so bear with me. Let's say that I have a one big circle (circle A), then I have multiple circles whose centres are on the edge of the circle A. Now I want to do the following: changing the size of the big circle (for example making it smaller), but I want the centres of small circles to stay connected on the edge and also get smaller proportionally. Is this possible? What am I looking for and how is it called?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to programming, maybe you're looking for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I have used tag "adobe-illustrator" thinking that it would post it into relevant category. Is it possible to move this question to the proposed thread or do I have to delete this one and post new one again?

Comment: You can move it to related programming sites but unfortunately not the graphic design site without flagging the attention of a ♦ moderator. So I think best to close it and ask a new question!